# Implications of convergence in quadratic mean over convergence in the 4-th mean

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, self-learning, expected-value, mean-square-error

I am trying to understand whether the convergence in quadratic mean of a sequence $X_n$ to some $X$ has implications over its own convergence in the $4$-th mean to the same $X$. Are there any theoretical results on this subject?

Comment: Just checking. When you say convergence in quadratic mean, do you mean $\mathbb{E}[(X_n - X)^2] \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbb E\left[(X_n-X)^2\right]\to 0$, the 4-th moment may not exist. 
Say, let $X=0$, $X_n=Y/n$, where $Y$ has Pareto distribution with pdf 
$$
f_Y(t) = \frac{3}{t^4}I_{\{t\geq 1\}}.
$$
Then 
$$\mathbb E\left[(X_n-X)^2\right] = \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb E\left[Y^2\right] = \frac{3}{n^2}\to 0$$
and 
$$
\mathbb E\left[(X_n-X)^4\right] = \frac{1}{n^4}\mathbb E\left[Y^4\right] = \infty.
$$
Vice versa, convergence in $4$-th mean implies convergence in quadratic mean since 
$$
\mathbb E[X^2] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb E[X^4]}.
$$

**ADDED**

Even if a fourth moment exists, convergence in quadratic mean does not imply convergence in $4$-th order mean.

In the above example take $X=0$ and $$X_n=\frac{Y}{n}\cdot I_{\{Y<n^4\}}=\begin{cases}\frac{Y}{n}, & Y<n^4 \cr 0, & Y \geq n^4\end{cases} $$
Then 
$$\mathbb E[(X_n-X)^2]=\mathbb E[X_n^2] =\frac1{n^2} \int_1^{n^4}t^2 \frac{3}{t^4}\,dt \to 0$$
but
$$\mathbb E[(X_n-X)^4]=\mathbb E[X_n^4] =\frac1{n^4} \int_1^{n^4}t^4 \frac{3}{t^4}\,dt = 3\frac{n^4-1}{n^4}\to 3.$$

Comment: Thank you. Assume that the fourth moment exists. Can you use some version of the continuous mapping theorem to show that the convergence in quadratic mean implies convergence in the 4-th mean?

Comment: You did not assumed in the question that $4$th moment exists. Newertheless, convergence in mean of order $k$ **does not imply** convergence in mean of any orders $m>k$, and imply convergence in mean of orders **less** that $k$. I added the corresponding modification to example.